# What are the dimensions of the joint between the tools and body on a Leatherman Surge?

Tags: tool-modification

I'm modifying a Leatherman Surge, and in the process I'm custom building some new tools to go in it. For this, I need the exact measurements and shape of some of the mechanisms used in the tool:

1. The swiveled locking mechanism. I have previously found a website which hosted this information, but it went down.
2. The universal shank that is used to connect jig saw blades to jig saws. This is also used in the Leatherman Surge but I don't think it is proprietary/unique.

A schematic diagram would be most helpful if someone has or can create one.

Comment: _I have previously found a website which hosted this information, but it went down._ What was the website link? This is asking for a trip with the wayback machine.

Comment: A picture of both the tool and one to help identify the part in question would help here as well.

Answer (score 2):

I was one of a few machinists that made the main pivot pin that links the Leatherman tools in the holder. Because the (stainless steel pin) material was very difficult to work down to the +-.0005 dimensions indicated using standard machine tooling, Leatherman made ongoing changes to the dimensions and material for cost effectiveness. The previous post, buy or use an appropriate caliper to measure would be the best if you are custom making your own tools to mount.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend buying a pair of calipers and taking the measurements yourself. If you are making modifications and parts yourself the calipers will be a welcome addition to your tools.

Comment: Welcome! This doesn't really answer the question.